# Topics missing after upgrading from jforum 2.1.6 to 2.1.9

Tags: java, forum

I have just upgraded to `Jforum 2.1.9` , I can `login` but although it says `Our users have posted a total of 11,205` messages , no messages, topics or forums are listed. I'm using `Tomcat 7.0.30` and `MySql 5.0.77`, I did the upgrade as follows:

- Ran `mysqldump` on my database
- Created a new database and populated with output of `mysqldump`
- Modified my existing `2.1.6` installation to use new database and checked that it still worked
- Unzipped `jforum-2.1.9.zip` to local directory
- Changed `2.1.6` installation to look back at its original database
- Ran `mysql_2.1.6_to_2.1.7.sql` against the new database
- Ran `mysql_2.1.7_to_2.1.8.sql` against the new database
  (Couldnt see an upgrade script for 2.1.8 to 2.1.9)
- Created `META-INF/context.xml` (which defines a data source for new database, not sur eif required)
- Copied `WEB-INF/config/jforum-custom.conf` from my `2.1.6` installation into `WEB-INF/config` in `jforum2.1.9` directory in same place and modifed to point to new database
- Modified forum.link and homepage link to point to new deploy path
- Deployed this modified version

So I now have deployed:

```
http://machinename/forum (2.1.6 pointing to old database)
http://machinename/forum2.1.9 (2.1.9 pointing to new database)
```

As I said earlier I can get to `http://machinename/forum2.1.9` and login but no topics/messages ectera are listed. Similarly if I go into Admin Control Panel Users and Groups looks okay but Forums is empty

If I go to the database itself and look at jforum_topics and jforum_forums the data is there.

I then noticed the lucene section in Admin and that the Number of documents was zero. So I configured a date range and created a new index, the Number of Documents field increased. If I then go back to the forum and do a search the search says it has found some documents but still does not show any of the results.

Answer (score 1):

if you are upgrading from 2.1.6 to 2.1.9, and you are only upgrading database changes, you also require to do changes in your data directory, where you uploaded document and all is uploaded.

So download 2.1.7 source, run 2.1.6 to 2.17 script and check, it is working or not, If this works repeat it two times more(2.1.7-> 2.18 and 2.1.8 -> 2.1.9.

And also [check this](http://jforum.net/upgrading217to218.jsp)